# Two connections with mongoose in the same application. The second connection is to connect the first dependent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem. I want to have two connections to the database. In the first database, I have the login information and the database name where are the other information. It is possible to do this using Node.js, mongoose and mongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
var mongoose1       = require('mongoose'),
    mongoose2       = require('mongoose');

mongoose1.connect('mongodb://FirstIPAdrress:27017/firstDatabase');

//get values for the second database via find

mongoose2.connect('mongodb://SecondIPAdrress:27017/secondDatabase');
```